# Get Date obj as percentage of that day Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, percentage

I'm given time in millis and I can convert that to date obj with

```
currentDate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stamp/1000.0).date()
```

I'm trying to get this time as a percentage of that given day so say its 12:00pm I'd like to get 50% as output.

Here's my attempt

```
currentDate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stamp/1000.0).date()
NextDay_Date = currentDate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
start_of_next_day=NextDay_Date.replace(hour=00, minute=00)

difference=start_of_next_day.timestamp()*1000 -currentDate.timestamp()*1000

milis_in_a_day=86400000 

percent_of_day=difference/milis_in_a_day
```

There has to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: What is `time_stamp` here?

Comment: miliseconds since Unix Epoch

Comment: Given Unix time `t` in seconds since the epoch, the day fraction is simply `(t % 86400) / 86400`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just count the number of microseconds passed today, by just using the time part of the date.

```py
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.now()

microseconds_today = (
    (
        (
            (today.hour * 60) + today.minute
        ) * 60 + today.second
    ) * 1_000_000 + today.microsecond
)
print(microseconds_today / 86_400_000_000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically on the right path, only thing I could think of to be a bit more "readable" is to use `timedelta` from `datetime`. Note the fully qualified names used below - `datetime` in particular can be a bit confusing to read, definitely suggest referencing the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

```
import datetime
TOTAL_DAY_SECS = 86400.0

def timedelta_percentage(input_datetime):
    d = input_datetime - datetime.datetime.combine(input_datetime.date(), datetime.time())
    return d.total_seconds() / TOTAL_DAY_SECS

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(f"'datetime.now()': {now}")
answer = round(timedelta_percentage(now) * 100, 2)
print(f"Percentage of day complete, based on 'now': {answer}%")
```

Output:

```
'datetime.now()': 2021-04-23 09:38:16.026000
Percentage of day complete, based on 'now': 40.16%
```

You could certainly adapt this to be more precise using microseconds, depending how granular of an answer you need.